# How to display elements of a 2-d array in a JavaFX GUI

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, javafx, gridpane, borderpane

I'm extremely new JavaFX (and any GUI for that matter), and I'm having troubles with understanding some concepts. That said, I have 10x10 multi-dimensional array that stores random `int`'s within a class that extends `GridPane`, and I'm having troubles understanding how I would display each random `int` value graphically in the center of a `BorderPane` of another class. I would like each `int` of every element to be shown in a shape of sorts uniformly. I don't want to know an exact solution. I just want to be aware of what options and steps I should take e.g. imports I should be aware of etc. Found this image from a different post, but this the kind of layout I imagine, except I don't need them to be buttons

[image]

Comment: Showing an illustration of your desired view would be helpful.

Comment: Just added an image from a different post. That's pretty much the layout I would like, I just don't need them to be buttons. Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a (probably nested) loop and traverse the 2d-array. On each cycle get the int value from the class and put into one of appropriate [built-in layout panes of JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm). I suggest to use another general/master `GridPane` or `TilePane`. Then put this master pane to center of `BorderPane`.

Comment: Two things, and excuse my ignorance. When you say get the `int` value from the class, are you referring to the value at each index of the array? And you mentioned a general/master `GridPane`, what is that? Another one as in another class aside from my class that extends GridPane?

Comment: @ZFN7. 1) No, the value of the your class that extends Gridpane. 2) Yes, to get the grid view like in your image you need to use one of built-in layouts.